# Searching only a portion of a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, search, matrix

I have a symmetric matrix and I am curious if it is possible to only search the upper triangle portion of the matrix using np.where. That is, is there a way to either delete the lower triangular portion of the matrix using a loop or a function so I can search the upper triangular portion of the matrix with np.where?

Comment: Short answer--yes it's possible. However, I don't believe there is a way around pulling out sub-rows from each row in the matrix depending on whether it is in the upper triangular or not, and I doubt it would be faster than searching the matrix as a whole. What is the goal? There may be another way around what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What I want is to do is select the variables which meet a minimum correlation threshold. So if I have, say a .7 threshold and a matrix
[[1 ,0.42,  0.78], [0.42, 1, 0.73], [0.78,  0.73, 1], I want to know which variable pairs exceed .7. So I would want to return (var1, var3) and (var2, var3). But if I just use numpy.where, I'll get redundant pairings if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1 ,0.42, 0.78], [0.42, 1, 0.73], [0.78, 0.73, 1]])
# k=1 excludes diagonal correlation is 1 
np.where(np.triu(a > 0.7, k=1))
```